# How i can parse a string from every domain?

Tags: python, dnsimple

I'm new to python scripting and got some task.

I need to write a script that will make a GET request for all domains, parce the EXPIRES_ON date, compare with the current date, and if there is less than a month left, extend it by 1 year with a POST request.

The only thing i need is to come up with right solution for parsing this date. Some people recommend me to do this with cycle. Any thoughts?

language: python

source: dnsimple

example of date: 'expires_on': '2022-01-25'

Comment: Please add an example of the dates you want to parse.

Comment: add to my question